# How to pass the selected value from select box to a PHP function?

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu

I have select box for company whose values are populated from DB and I also have another select box for department. Now I have a PHP function to get the values of department if we pass the id of company into it. I have to use this function to populate the department select box every i select the company name.

hence,
How to pass the selected value from select box to a PHP function?

thanx , every answer is appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck, can you share some code please?

Comment: what are you trying to do? sounds like you want to change  the select box values of department according to any selection made in the company drop down. Am i right?

Comment: @Shakti U r absolutely right...

Comment: Reading some Ajax and Jquery stuff will help you

Comment: AJAX is your friend in this case.. the link posted by Catalin is nice and look pretty simple to implement, assuming you can use jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at this: http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You should use a js obviously, would have been helpful if you posted the code but write an

> onchange="somefn()"

in the select box and write in the js function an ajax call to populate the second selectbox.